# How to have 2 column ListBox using Dictionary object to delete duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to create a listbox with 2 columns (1 column with the names and another with countries) and I am using Dictionary object to delete duplicates.

My code is working but only for 1 column, maybe someone knows how I can have the 2 columns together?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Dict As Object
Dim Key As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim C As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = Sheets("Details")

With Sheets("Details")

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each C In data.Range("P2:P" & ws.Range("P" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If C.Value <> "" Then ' <-- skip empty cells
            If Not Dict.exists(C.Value) Then
                Dict.Add C.Value, 1
            End If
        End If
    Next C
End With

' loop through all unique keys, and add them to the listbox
For Each Key In Dict.Keys
    List_Bene.AddItem Key

Next Key

End Sub
```

[image: Data for the ListBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the values together, I suggest using a delimiter in case you need to split them out again later. I'll use a pipe (|) here as that is unlikely to be present in text.

```
With Sheets("Details")
    dim keystr as string
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each C In data.Range("P2:P" & ws.Range("P" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If C.Value <> "" Then ' <-- skip empty cells
            keystr = c.value & "|" & c.offset(0, 3).value
            If Not Dict.exists(keystr) Then
                Dict.Add keystr, 1
            End If
        End If
    Next C
End With
```

if you need to split later:

```
For Each Key In Dict.Keys
    List_Bene.AddItem split(Key, "|")(0) & " " & split(Key, "|")(1)
Next Key
```

If you are using two columns in the list box:

```
With Me.List_Bene
Dim i As Long
i = 0
For Each Key In Dict.Keys
    List_Bene.AddItem
    .List(i, 0) = Split(Key, "|")(0)
    .List(i, 1) = Split(Key, "|")(1)
    i = i + 1
Next Key
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The final idea is to use 1 value (name + country) (selected by the excel user) to be paste in a excel cell (sheet1.range("A1" for the name and "B1" for the country). So I thought it would be better to have 2 columns like `List_Bene.ColumnCount = 2
For i = 0 To ltrow

List_Bene.AddItem grid.Range("P2:S").Value
List_Bene.List(1, 1) = grid("P2:P" & grid.Range("P" & grid.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
List_Bene.List(1, 2) = grid("S2:S" & grid.Range("P" & grid.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` However, this is not working. Plus in the ListBox cant have duplicate.

Comment: I added in an edit, I think that's what you're looking for?